# Ubuntu 18.04 installer unable to detect PCIe NVMe SSD

Tags: dual-boot, ssd, raid, nvme, pcie

I have a HP Omen dg0019tx laptop with Win 10, NVIDIA RTX2080, 2 numbers of 1 TB PCIe NVMe SSD configured as RAID 0 Volume. I tried to dual boot it with Ubuntu 18.04, however, Ubuntu is unable to detect the SSD. I tried following solutions available over internet.

1. Disable Fast Boot: Unable to detect SSD
2. Disable Secure Boot: Unable to detect SSD
3. Boot with Legacy mode: Unable to detect SSD
4. Changed RAID to non-RAID: Unable to detect SSD, Unable to boot into windows, reinstalled window
5. Booted window to safe mode using bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal: Able to boot in windows safe mode. then changed RAID to non-RAID, but again windows failed to boot, so again reinstalled windows
6. Added nvme_load=YES in ubuntu Boot options: Still not able to detect SSD.
7. lsblk also doesn't list nvme. It only shows pendrive used for Ubuntu live

Another point is that HP BIOS for this laptop don't have option to turn RAID to AHCI. It allows only RAID to non-RAID.

So, is there any way to dual boot this system with UBUNTU? Kindly help me out.

Comment: I tried adding nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=5500 during ubuntu boot installer, but it also didn't work. Then I repeated all the above steps with Ubuntu 19.04 but nothing worked. I tried updating the firmware of SSD (it's WD PC SN720) but that was already up-to-date.

Comment: I'm in the same situation on an HP envy x360, I can't get Ubuntu to see the PCIe NVMe SSD